# VBA write text equivalent in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I have the below in VBA that I use to write an array in a specific format to a CSV file (partly this is to get aorund excel putting "" around every cell when saving normally).

I am now trying to transfer accross to VB.net. 
I have had a look aorund and tried various iterations of options to no avail.

```
Sub WriteCSV(varHoldingsArray, strTempLocation)

Dim i, j As Integer
Dim strCompiled As String

Open strTempLocation For Output As #1

For i = LBound(varHoldingsArray, 2) To UBound(varHoldingsArray, 2)

    For j = LBound(varHoldingsArray, 1) To UBound(varHoldingsArray, 1)

        Select Case j

            Case Is > LBound(varHoldingsArray, 2)

            strCompiled = strCompiled & varHoldingsArray(j, i)

            Case LBound(varHoldingsArray, 2)

            strCompiled = strCompiled & "," & varHoldingsArray(j, i)

        End Select

    Next j

If i <> UBound(varHoldingsArray, 2) Then
    strCompiled = strCompiled & vbNewLine
End If

Next i

Print #1, strCompiled

 Close #1

End Sub
```

My issue comes around opening the file printing to it.

I replaced:

```
Open strTempLocation For Output As #1
```

with:

```
File.Create(strTempLocation) For Output As #1
```

althought the "For Output" part as used in VBA doesn't seem to be expected (this is where I get lost). I have referenced System and System.IO in the project.

I'm then after the the .net equivalents of the following at the end:

```
Print #1, strCompiled

Close #1
```

Comment: Have you tried using the File System Object for this instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A easy method would be

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("c:\filename", "text", False)
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem.WriteAllText(v=vs.110).aspx)